# convert json dict to array in python

Tags: python, json

I have data like and I would like to covert it to an array in python, this is the data and code I have tried below

```
{
 "appUuid": "aaaa-bbbb-cccc",
 "SystemId": null,
 "city": "Lancaster",
 "state": "NY",
 "zipCode": "140",
 "field1": "others",
 "field2": "others"
}
{
 "appUuid": "bbbb-dddd-eeee",
 "SystemId": null,
 "city": "Alden ",
 "state": "NY",
 "zipCode": "140",
 "field1": "others",
 "field2": "others"
}
```

I would like to convert it to something like this

```
[{
 "appUuid": "aaaa-bbbb-cccc",
 "SystemId": null,
 "city": "Lancaster",
 "state": "NY",
 "zipCode": "140",
 "field1": "others",
 "field2": "others"
},
{
 "appUuid": "bbbb-dddd-eeee",
 "SystemId": null,
 "city": "Alden ",
 "state": "NY",
 "zipCode": "140",
 "field1": "others",
 "field2": "others"
}]
```

I tried

```
data1 = json.loads(data)
for item in data1:
  print(data1)
```

But is returning only one record multiple times, see output

```
{"appUuid": "aaaa-bbbb-cccc", "SystemId": null, "city": "Lancaster", "state": "NY", "zipCode": "140", "field1": "others","field2": "others"}
{"appUuid": "aaaa-bbbb-cccc", "SystemId": null, "city": "Lancaster", "state": "NY", "zipCode": "140", "field1": "others","field2": "others"}
{"appUuid": "aaaa-bbbb-cccc", "SystemId": null, "city": "Lancaster", "state": "NY", "zipCode": "140", "field1": "others","field2": "others"}
```

Please help, thanks

Comment: The initial set of data in your post is not valid JSON. Also, why not debug this? Print `item` and see what it is. You're incorrectly printing `data1` each time.

Comment: Your input data is not valid json and could not possibly have been the input in `data1 = json.loads(data)`

Comment: `print(item) `  you are printing the whole data1

Comment: @jarmod and micah, that is how the data is in the database, I can't change the source format

Comment: If that's literally how you receive the data (as a single string) then you can't parse it with json.loads, as it stands, because it's not valid JSON. Parse the individual objects out of it and json.loads each one individually, or get clever and modify the entire string to turn it into valid JSON.

Answer (score 1):

You should just print like this. The data you received is already as you wanted.

```
data1 = json.loads(data)
for key, value in data1.items():
    print(key, value)
```

Comment: this only prints the the key and not the value

Comment: If you just want value use it like data1.values() in for loop. If you want to see both key and value use it like "for key, value in data1.items()